# Como separar HTML do PHP

Tags: php, html, estilo-de-codificação

Li em vários lugares que não se deve misturar PHP com HTML e vice-versa,
Como então poderia separar esse código por exemplo:

```
<?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\trabweb\sessaoBD.php' ?> <!--entra na sessão e na database -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <title>Trabalho web</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/trabweb/css/style_hashbase.css"> <!--css do site N-O-D-E, apenas algumas modificações feitas -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\trabweb\header.html' ?> <!--cabeçalho da pagina-->

  <div id="content">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="list">
<div id="post">

  <?php if ($login === true and $_SESSION["user_name"] === "lucas"): ?> <!--checa se é o ADMIN, caso sim ele podera fazer um novo post -->
    <a href="http://localhost/trabweb/crianewpost.php">*NEW POST*</br></br></a> <!--redirige a pagina de criar um novo post  -->
    <?php endif; ?>

<!--mostra todos posts na tela -->
          <?php
          $sql =  "select titulo,id from POSTS";
          //$sql = "DELETE FROM POSTS" ;
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          if ($conn->query($sql) === false) {
              echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
          }
          if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              // output data of each row
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo  '<a method="get" href= "http://localhost/trabweb/db/seleposts.php?posts_id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row["titulo"].'</a> <br>'; //cada post é um link para o seu conteudo
              }
          } else {
              echo "0 results";
          }
          ?>

</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Se você quer montar o HTML com o PHP, essencialmente terá que *misturar* os dois. O que você pode fazer aí é separar as coisas: PHP que define layout de PHP que define lógica, como por exemplo a execução da SQL.

Comment: Lucas a melhor forma de separar o php do html é usando algum framework de templates.
Atualmente o Twig (template engine) ou blade atende bastante essa necessidade. Se você você estiver usando o php sem framework o twig pode cair muito bem...

Comment: estuda sobre MVC uma boa seria utilizar uma framework chamada Phalcon a estrutura dela ja permite criação de layouts e a performance dela é a melhor

Comment: Já eu recomendaria ficar bem longe de frameworks por hora. Se não domina o básico, não tem sentido querer dominar o *avançado*. Como sempre digo: frameworks são soluções para problemas específicos. Usá-los para uma finalidade diferente é um erro que traz mais prejuízos que benefícios.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiro, usando caminhos fixos vão complicar para você publicar. No servidor não será esse caminho.

Segundo, quase tudo o que você vê por aí sobre programação é escrito por gente que não entende do que está falando, são pessoas que também leram em algum lugar e ficam repetindo sem entender o motivador e contexto. Vira um "telefone sem fio". Só acredite em coisas que expliquem o porquê.

Não dá para separar totalmente em páginas que precisam ser construídas dinamicamente (e é um erros as pessoas tentarem fazer tudo ser dinâmico). Dá para minimizar o uso e separar a lógica mais complexa em outro arquivo. Mas só faz sentido como uma forma de organizar tudo coerentemente, só fazer uma separação simples não ajuda muito, é só pra "cumprir tabela".

Se precisa de comentários é porque o código está confuso demais. Não vou consertar vários problemas nele, só mostrar o que foi perguntado.

Para fazer certo seria complicado mostrar aqui, mas a grosso modo basicamente é abstração do que precisa separar.

```
<?php include 'sessaoBD.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>Trabalho web</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_hashbase.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'header.html' ?>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="page">
      <div id="list">
         <div id="post">
         <?php if ($login and $_SESSION["user_name"] === "lucas"): ?>
             <a href="crianewpost.php">*NEW POST*</br></br></a>
         <?php endif;
         getPosts();
         ?>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Postagens.php

```
<?php
function getPosts() {
    $sql =  "select titulo, id from POSTS";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($conn->query($sql) === false) echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  '<a method="get" href= "db/seleposts.php?posts_id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row["titulo"].'</a> <br>';
        }
    } else echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/FunctionSepareted.php).

Ao contrário do que está sendo dito por outros, eu não recomendo estudar MVC. Primeiro porque é mais complicado para um iniciante e que está tendo dificuldade bem básicas ainda. Segundo porque há uma corrente que já percebeu que MVC é canhão para matar passarinho na maioria dos cenários web. Ele serve para projetos grandes com muita lógica, onde realmente precisa gerenciar complexidade, mas para pequenos projetos, que é a esmagadora maioria dos casos ele só adiciona complexidade sem trazer vantagens, por isso *frameworks* mais recentes tem preferido uma abordagem mais simples (e não estou recomendando o uso deles, antigos ou modernos).

Comment: É apenas um trabalho da universidade, então não vou precisar publicar.

"Quase tudo o que você vê por aí sobre programação é escrito por gente que não entende do que está falando", anotado : ) .
  
os comentários são porque o professor pediu mesmo.

Agradeceria se me falasse algum desses erros.

"E não estou recomendando o uso deles, antigos ou modernos" anotado.

Vou deixar como está então, obrigado.

Comment: A lista é grande demais pra listar :) O modelo básico que está seguindo funciona, o erro é como organizar isso da maneira como se faz em situações reais de mercado.

Comment: (T_T) , : D , vou perguntar ao professor quando tiver a opurtunidade.

Answer (score 2):

Cara, um pouco de PHP e HTML sempre acaba misturando, por exemplo os includes e o IF podem ficar ai tranquilamente, o que você poderia separar é essa parte:

```
<?php
   $sql =  "select titulo,id from POSTS";
   //$sql = "DELETE FROM POSTS" ;
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($conn->query($sql) === false) {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo  '<a method="get" href= "http://localhost/trabweb/db/seleposts.php?posts_id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row["titulo"].'</a> <br>'; //cada post é um link para o seu conteudo
       }
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }
?>
```

Ai você tem duas opções, ou colocar esse código em um arquivo separado e simplesmente incluir ele ai, ou criar um arquivo e transformar esse código em uma função, então no código HTML você só chama essa função.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que um primeiro passo para você poder entender isso melhor, seria estudando a arquitetura [MVC](https://tableless.com.br/mvc-afinal-e-o-que/), que é uma das arquiteturas de software mais comuns. Já vai lhe abrir vários horizontes de como seu projeto pode ser bem dividido e organizado.

No seu caso, como está trabalhando com PHP, também recomendaria que desse uma olhada no framework [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/), assim como vários outros frameworks, o CodeIgniter trabalha com a arquitetura MVC, "obrigando" o desenvolvedor a trabalhar em cima dela.

Há várias outras opções de framework em PHP, como [Zend](https://framework.zend.com/), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), etc. Mas acredito que dentre a maioria o CodeIgniter é um dos que possui a menor curva de aprendizado, melhor para iniciantes.

Comment: E realmente nunca vai ser regra, cada caso é um caso, então pode ser sim que você tenha que misturar PHP com HTML, não se sinta culpado por isso.

Comment: Meu professor disse que não deveria ser usado essas frameworks (esqueci de ter comentado) , mas não custa estudalas.

Comment: @lucaspelepek compreendo, acredito que a resposta do Maniero está bem de acordo na verdade, espero que tenha conseguido sanar suas dúvidas.